# Is there a way to search for an item in the first term in a multidimensional array?

Tags: python

I'm adding data into a **multi-dimensional array** from a table with SQL.

Since there are multiples of the same data, I want to be able to only add it if it's not already in the array, This is the code I have. As it is, it works fine, except I want row[1] and row[2] to be appended and help together in a 2d array seperate from the others, but when I try and do this I get an error saying it is out of range

```py
    c.execute("SELECT Subject_name, Unit_Number, Unit_title, Topic_title FROM topics WHERE Subject_name = '%s'"%(str(subjectnames[choosenotes-1])))
    x=0
    unitnames = []
    for row in c.fetchall():
        if row[1] in unitnames:
            pass
        elif row[1] not in unitnames:
            unitnames.append(row[1])
            unitnames.append(row[2])
        else:
            print("Error")
        x=x+1
```

When the array is printed after this, I get ['1', 'Motion, Energy and Matter', '2', 'Electricity and light', '3', 'Oscillations and nuclei', '4', 'Fields and options', '5', 'Practical examination'], when I want [['1', 'Motion, Energy and Matter'],['2', 'Electricity and light'],['3', 'Oscillations and nuclei'],['4', 'Fields and options'],['5', 'Practical examination']].

Comment: When you say *array*, do you mean a `list`, a `np.ndarray` or something else?

Comment: I edited your Question to improve readability. You should add some example data like `myArray = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 7]]`

Answer (score 1):

Since you're adding data from a table I'll assume you are talking about a 2-dimensional structure (you don't specify if it is a Python array or list or something else) here.

If you want to test for every row:

```
for row in my_array:
    if x in row: 
        # add it.
```

#### Adendum

If you want to know if some value is the **first** element on a sequence you should use:

```
for row in my_array:
    if x != row[0]:       # Check x against row's first item. 
        row.insert(0, x)  # insert x as first item of the row.
```

The following:

```
sequence[0] == value
```

not the same as:

```
value in sequence
```

The last checks if `value` is IN the sequence no matter the position.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, and lack of info, I've tried doing this but no luck:
`for row in c.fetchall():`
        `if row[1] == unitnames[0]:`
            `pass`
        `elif row[1] != unitnames[0]:`
            `unitnames[x].append(row[1])`
            `unitnames[x].append(row[2])`
        `else:`
            `print("Error")`
        `x=x+1`

Comment: I edited the question since I've made a bit of progress, should be a bit easier to read this time

Answer (score 0):

You could simply iterate through an array of arrays by using something similar to the following. This checks if the entry is in any one of the 2d subarray's first elements. If it is not in any subarray first element, then it triggers logic so that you can add it to the array.

```
found = False
searchParameter = 'j'
array = [['x', 'y' , 'z'], ['a', 'b', 'c']]
for subArray in array:
    if searchParameter == subArray[0]:
        found = True

if(not found):
    print("Adding it to the array!..")
    #your_append_action_here.
```

Comment: Your code is wrong, `searchParameter in subArray[0]`  do not does what you think here. In the first iteration `subArray[0]` is just `'x'` in the second `'a'`.

Comment: This was on purpose. The question from DynamicNight seems to me focused on first element matching.  specifically checking the first element of each subarray, not checking the entire 2d array. I presume he's checking for some ID metadata. His example showed the a similar structure stating that "This works for 1D arrays". Therefore, this is merely an expansion of that functionality to 2D

Comment: Yes, then you should use `searchParameter == subArray[0]` instead, don't you think?

Comment: Fair enough. I'll edit it, as it improves readability to have an '==' instead of the keyword 'in' in this context.